# How can I get list of subscribed clients in autobahn.ws?

Tags: websocket, autobahn, crossbar, wamp-protocol, autobahnws

Now I'm developing chat using wamp-protocol, crossbar.io, autobahn.ws.
We have rooms only for two clients. I need to define if other client is in room, if it in I publish new message in other case I make request to GCM.
Every room has own uri like 'com.example.chat.'

That's why I need to get list of clients in specified uri 'com.example.chat.'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible via the meta-API - see http://crossbar.io/docs/Subscription-Meta-Events-and-Procedures/

So you'd retrieve the list of subscribers for the room topic by doing

```
session.call("wamp.subscription.list_subscribers", [23560753]).then(session.log, session.log)
```

where you'd use the subscription ID assigned to the topic by Crossbar.io.